# Npm erro EPRM errno -1 in android

Tags: android, node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/ASTRO/projects/PokeXD/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/ASTRO/projects/PokeXD/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/ASTRO/projects/PokeXD/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/ASTRO/projects/PokeXD/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -1,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js',
npm ERR!     dest: '/storage/emulated/0/ASTRO/projects/PokeXD/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../detect-libc/bin/detect-libc.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/ASTRO/projects/PokeXD/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc',
npm ERR!   parent: 'PokeXD'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.astrosohu/files/home/.npm/_logs/2020-11-12T05_56_31_566Z-debug.log
$ root/Administrator
bash: root/Administrator: No such file or direc
```

Thats the error showing when i try to install
`npm install quick.db`
Android and i am using ASTRO App can be found in Play Store
Also when I try to install pm2
Then also similar thing happened and i cant even find solution for it so please help me

Comment: What OS are you trying to install this package on? (Chrome OS, Windows, etc.)

Comment: Android Astro app

Comment: @snowy.dbf astro app android

Comment: well, it says right here `The operation was rejected by your operating system`. This can either be because you don't have permission to install it or it might just not run on android at all.